# how to make uitableviewcontroller at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a uitableviewcontroller with static cells, they are 4 cells.

so the result is like this:
[image]

as you see there is a white space at the button, i want to change the color of it, i change the color of the view that comes with the UITableViewController, but that didn't help. i read i understood that i have to make the table view scrol to the buttom of the screen,

i tried this code (i found on internet)

```
if tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height
        {
            let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)
            tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        }
```

but nothing changed, i want to ask you if you know a solution please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you use storyboard

  1.- Select your tableView.
  [image: tableView]

  2.- Go to the Inspector and change color of your background in "View"

[image: change BackgroundColor]

3.- Run

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the background color of your tableView just add this `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()` the tableView should be at the top of the view in my opinion, so I would recommend to change the background color.

Add this row in your `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve it:

1. Set the height of cell equals to Screen Height / 4
2. add a constraints to `UITableView` to the the bottom of the container
   of the `UITableView` and set its value to 0 (from storyboard)